# vnc server cannot apply subscription

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I installed VNC server on my Ubuntu 18.04 pc, however I cannot enable the cloud connectivity. As per the docs I need to run commands with `sudo` to start the VNC server in service mode. So I tried this command:

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

But when I try to login to the VNC server desktop application, it says `"Administrative privileges are required for this operation"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: What docs are you looking at?

Comment: this [link](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/unix-start-stop.html#unix-start-stop),,

Answer (score 12):

You need to tell VNC what the email address / credentials are to use

The tool to download is VNC Connect [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/). Download this and run the .deb file on the laptop.

Once installed, from the command line run

```
sudo vnclicensewiz
```

This starts the gui where you enter your RealVNC account details.

You then need to start the server on the laptop. Test it with

```
sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

starting the service temporarily.

To start the service on every boot, do

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

Comment: You'll need to run `vnclicensewiz` using `sudo` to fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps running `gksudo vncserver-x11` would do the trick for you. Here you have a similar example (I'd say that this is actually a duplicate post and that question and answer were what you were looking for):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/148395/how-do-i-get-around-administrator-priviliges-are-required-for-this-task-when-ins

Comment: I am using ubntu 18.04 as what I have read gksudo is no longer available since 13.04..

Comment: I reinstalled gksudo.. I was able to run vnc but there is an error it says, VNC is in User Mode

Comment: @BakerStreet maybe this official doc could help you with that error https://archive.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/4.6/unix/x0.html